# Child form always stay above of main form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm using delphi 2007 and each time which I create a new form using a code like this

```
var
  Child : TFrmChild;
begin
  Child:=TFrmChild.Create(Self);
  Child.Show();
end;
```

The *child* form is shown and appears above all others forms , that is ok, but when a click in the main form the child form stays above of the main form. so i have two questions

1. why the *child* form stay above of the main form even if a click in the main form?
2. How i can make which the main form stay over all others forms when i click on it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

this is the dfm of the child form

```
object FrmChild: TFrmChild
  Left = 549
  Top = 308
  Caption = 'FrmChild'
  ClientHeight = 228
  ClientWidth = 213
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two top level windows. The main form is the owner of the child form. Owned windows always appear above their owners, that's just one of the rules of Windows.

Note that by owner I am referring to the Windows concept rather than the Delphi concept.

The [Windows Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic explains the rules. The key statement is:

> An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.

As for how to make you app behave differently I'm not so sure. If you make your child form unowned then it will have its own taskbar button and it won't be minimised when the main form is minimised, for example.

Answer (score 3):

This has been reported to [QualityCentral](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=49410). The simple workaround is to set

```
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;
```

in your project's .dpr file.  The downside is loss of some Vista functionality.

There is another workaround, but it is clumsy and has other problems (see the link to QC).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Which Windows Vista functionality i can loss if I set the `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` to `false`?

Comment: Whilst you are correct that this has been reported to QC, you should note that it has been closed on the grounds of the behaviour being as designed.

Comment: @DelphiNewbie - I do not use Vista so I do not know, but I believe it is related to how the application appears on the taskbar.

Comment: @DelphiNewbie - There is a description of MainFormOnTaskbar in http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/hide_taskbutton.htm

Comment: It may be on QualityCentral (bug db) but this isn't a bug, it's expected Windows platform behaviour.

Comment: I was having this same issue, and it appears this was the culprit. Thanks for the info on this side effect of setting MainFormOnTaskbar not mentioned in the help file.

Comment: I like their resolution: 'behavior as designed' [Ironic :) ]. Too bad Emba won't fix this issue.

Comment: GOOD TO KNOW: Quote from manual: "MainFormOnTaskBar must be true to use Windows Vista Aero effects. These include live taskbar thumbnails, Dynamic Windows, Windows Flip, and Windows Flip 3D"

Comment: Late comment - you can get some of the "Vista" effects using the [ITaskBarList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. Use `AddTab` in FormShow and `ActivateTab` in FormActivate, and `DeleteTab` in FormHide (or override DoShow,  Activate and DoHide). I have this working in D2007 on Windows 7 and 10

Answer (score 1):

Late answer - I have just worked around this issue. We wanted the Aero style ALT-TAB and WIN-TAB funtionality, but MainFormOnTaskBar caused some issues with a third-party component. (LMD Docking - if there was a docksite on the main form and a docksite on a child, dragging a docked item on the child brought the main form to the front)

The solution to this was to:

- Set Params.WndParent to 0 in CreateParams
- use the [ITaskBarList interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx) to manage the TaskBar tabs. This also adds the windows to the ALT-TAB and WIN-TAB handlers,

TaskBarList.pas

```
unit TaskbarList;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages,
  CommCtrl,
  ShlObj,
  SysUtils, Classes, ComCtrls;

const
  SID_ITaskbarList                            = '{56FDF342-FD6D-11D0-958A-006097C9A090}';
  SID_ITaskbarList2                           = '{602D4995-B13A-429B-A66E-1935E44F4317}';
  SID_ITaskbarList3                           = '{EA1AFB91-9E28-4B86-90E9-9E9F8A5EEFAF}';
  SID_ITaskbarList4                           = '{C43DC798-95D1-4BEA-9030-BB99E2983A1A}';

  CLSID_TaskbarList: TGUID                            = '{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}';

type
  ITaskbarList = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_ITaskbarList]
    function HrInit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function AddTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DeleteTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ActivateTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetActiveAlt(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITaskbarList2 = interface(ITaskbarList)
    [SID_ITaskbarList2]
    function MarkFullscreenWindow(hwnd: HWND; fFullscreen: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

type
  THUMBBUTTON = record
    dwMask: DWORD;
    iId: UINT;
    iBitmap: UINT;
    hIcon: HICON;
    szTip: packed array[0..259] of WCHAR;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
  end;
  tagTHUMBBUTTON = THUMBBUTTON;
  TThumbButton = THUMBBUTTON;
  PThumbButton = ^TThumbButton;

// THUMBBUTTON flags
const
  THBF_ENABLED        =  $0000;
  THBF_DISABLED       =  $0001;
  THBF_DISMISSONCLICK =  $0002;
  THBF_NOBACKGROUND   =  $0004;
  THBF_HIDDEN         =  $0008;
  THBF_NONINTERACTIVE = $10;
// THUMBBUTTON mask
  THB_BITMAP          =  $0001;
  THB_ICON            =  $0002;
  THB_TOOLTIP         =  $0004;
  THB_FLAGS           =  $0008;
  THBN_CLICKED        =  $1800;

const
  TBPF_NOPROGRESS    = 0;
  TBPF_INDETERMINATE = $1;
  TBPF_NORMAL        = $2;
  TBPF_ERROR         = $4;
  TBPF_PAUSED        = $8;

  TBATF_USEMDITHUMBNAIL   = $1;
  TBATF_USEMDILIVEPREVIEW = $2;

const
  STPF_NONE                       = $00000000;
  STPF_USEAPPTHUMBNAILALWAYS      = $00000001;
  STPF_USEAPPTHUMBNAILWHENACTIVE  = $00000002;
  STPF_USEAPPPEEKALWAYS           = $00000004;
  STPF_USEAPPPEEKWHENACTIVE       = $00000008;


type
  ITaskbarList3 = interface(ITaskbarList2)
    [SID_ITaskbarList3]
    function SetProgressValue(hwnd: HWND; ullCompleted: ULONGLONG;
      ullTotal: ULONGLONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetProgressState(hwnd: HWND; tbpFlags: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RegisterTab(hwndTab: HWND; hwndMDI: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UnregisterTab(hwndTab: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetTabOrder(hwndTab: HWND; hwndInsertBefore: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetTabActive(hwndTab: HWND; hwndMDI: HWND;
      tbatFlags: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarAddButtons(hwnd: HWND; cButtons: UINT;
      pButton: PThumbButton): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarUpdateButtons(hwnd: HWND; cButtons: UINT;
      pButton: PThumbButton): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarSetImageList(hwnd: HWND; himl: HIMAGELIST): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetOverlayIcon(hwnd: HWND; hIcon: HICON;
      pszDescription: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnailTooltip(hwnd: HWND; pszTip: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnailClip(hwnd: HWND; var prcClip: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITaskbarList4 = interface(ITaskbarList3)
    [SID_ITaskbarList4]

    function SetTabProperties (hwnd: HWND; stpFlags: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;

  end;

implementation

end.
```

BaseForm.pas:

```
unit BaseForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  TaskBarList;

type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    class var FTaskBarList: ITaskbarList;
  protected
    class function TaskBarList: ITaskbarList;
    procedure DoShow;override;
    procedure DoHide;override;
    procedure Activate;override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  BaseForm: TBaseForm;

implementation

uses
  ComObj;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TBaseForm }

procedure TBaseForm.Activate;
begin
  inherited;
  TaskBarList.ActivateTab(Handle);
end;

procedure TBaseForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TBaseForm.Create(Self).Show;
end;

constructor TBaseForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // remove taskbar button for Application.Handle
  TaskBarList.DeleteTab(Application.Handle);
end;

procedure TBaseForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Parent = nil) and (ParentWindow = 0) then // don't use on docked Windows
    Params.WndParent := 0;
end;

procedure TBaseForm.DoHide;
begin
  inherited;
  TaskBarList.DeleteTab(Handle);
end;

procedure TBaseForm.DoShow;
begin
  inherited;
  TaskBarList.AddTab(Handle);
end;

class function TBaseForm.TaskBarList: ITaskbarList;
var
  pIntF: IInterface;
begin
  if not assigned(FTaskBarList) then
  begin
    pIntF := CreateComObject(CLSID_TaskbarList);
    pIntF.QueryInterface(ITaskBarList, FTaskBarList);

    FTaskBarList.HrInit;
  end;
  Result := FTaskBarList;
end;

end.
```

NOTE: I haven't checked the HRESULTS using OleCheck as I would prefer it to fail silently in the field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your child form may be ALWAYS ON TOP FORM
2. U can use MDI Form (man form) and MDI Child form (child form). Or u can use MTI , check this article http://delphi.about.com/b/2010/02/23/tabbed-interface-mti-for-your-mdi-delphi-applications.htm

Comment: Thanks, but the `formstyle` property of my child form is set to `fsNormal`, also i don't want use a MDI interface.

Comment: You don't need to have an always on top form for this to happen. All you need is for the child form to be owned (in the windows sense of the term) by the main form.